# CMake: Executing a C++ file when building the project

Tags: c++, cmake

I am developing on a C++ project, and I want to execute a script on build to generate some files. I am not very familiar with CMake, so I need some help.

And by script I mean a .cpp file within the project.

I have managed to obtain the following:

```
   set(PrecisionCommand
      ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/matlab/matlabprecision.cpp
   )
   set(precision_output_files
      ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/work/variables.txt
   )

   add_custom_command(
      OUTPUT ${precision_output_files}
      COMMAND ${PrecisionCommand}
      COMMENT "Running ${PrecisionCommand}"
   )


   add_custom_target(allocate_generate DEPENDS ${precision_output_files})
```

And what happens now is that the matlabprecision.cpp file is being opened in a text editor, rather than being executed. How do I fix this?

Comment: You can't ‘execute’ a C++ file (don't call it a ‘script’). You'd have to compile it and execute the resulting binary. This smells like an [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem), what do you *really* want to achieve?

Comment: How would you expect it to be executed ? .cpp files need to be be compiled first so it can produce an executable.

Comment: I was thinking that it might be able to compile locally in some way. It might be an XY-problem. I have a huge structure within the source, that I want to export and save as a .txt-file at each build (this I wanted to perform in the .cpp file). It will allow me to have meta data for developing scripts around the software.

Comment: @c.jespersen Well, you'd have to compile it. Perhaps a proper target (`add_executable`) so that everything's setup for compilation, and a second target that depends on the first that executes it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `.c` file is not a script but a source file, you cannot directly execute it. However, you may first compile it into executable:

```
add_executable(PrecisionCommand ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/matlab/matlabprecision.cpp)
```

and then run that executable:

```
add_custom_command(
  OUTPUT ${precision_output_files}
  COMMAND PrecisionCommand
  COMMENT "Running PrecisionCommand"
```

)

Note, that *COMMAND* option uses **target name** for run the executable. CMake understand that usage and:

- Transform target name into the *path* to the executable.
- Add appropriate *dependencies* between creating executable and running it.

From documentation about [add_custom_command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_custom_command.html):

> If COMMAND specifies an executable target (created by ADD_EXECUTABLE) it will automatically be replaced by the location of the executable created at build time. Additionally a target-level dependency will be added so that the executable target will be built before any target using this custom command.